# AWS PowerUser with MFA (IAM policy)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I templated the PowerUser policy and added MFA condition, resulting in MFA-PowerUser like the following

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "NotAction": "iam:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

The description and intention is:

```
Provides full access to AWS services and resources, but does not allow management of Users and groups. MFA needed by login.
```

test on EC2 with policy simulator all EC2 actions are denied with the reason

```
implicitly denied (no matching statement)
```

Comment: solved by myself. Should give the environment variable MultiFactorAuthPresent into the simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved by myself. Should give the environment variable MultiFactorAuthPresent into the simulator